# On Heap double pointer Array is coded like single pointer to be written to a file

Tags: c++, struct, file-io, fwrite

I have an array that is already in heap (dynamic) memory. That's not very difficult to understand, but writing it to a file by means of the `fwrite()` function can be a bit tricky to understand if it's also a double pointer by a way I see online, which I don't understand logic-wise, which is what I'm trying to clear up here.

```
int ** A;
A = new int* [randomSize];
A[0] = new int [randomSize];
```

For example, a single pointer by `fwrite()` would look like:

```
fwrite(&A[0], sizeof(teststruct), 54, dogfile);
```

So logic-wise, to what I understand, `A[0]` is holding a pointer pointing to a de-referenced address. But with `fwrite()`, what you want is the address itself, so you put the `&` in front of the `A[0]`. The contents at that address is then written to the file (correct me if I'm wrong).

So, if that's how a single pointer array looks in the `fwrite()` function, I think the logic of a double pointer array should look something like:

```
fwrite(&A[0][0], sizeof(teststruct), 54, dogfile);
```

With the 1st `[0]` at `A[0][0]` as a pointer pointing to another address containing a pointer (the 2nd `[0]` in `&A[0][0]`), which holds the address for an actual value.

`fwrite()` uses that 2nd `[0]` which is being de-referenced to print the actual values located at that address out to a file 54 times. So, basically, the `&` in front of `A[0][0]` should give the address of whatever is being de-referenced so stuff can be printed to the file.

This is how I understand it, based on the logic of how I think the `fwrite()` function works.

However, I saw on the Internet a double pointer being used with `fwrite()` to print to a file with a single box array (`A[0]`) not a double box array (`A[0][0]`). It looked like:

```
fwrite(A[0], sizeof(teststruct), 54, dogfile);
```

It was explained that this way is how to print all the values to a file from the double pointer array row by row, which makes no sense to me at all because it's a single box (`A[0]`). Also, where's the `&` symbol that's suppose to be in front of the array?

Could someone who understand this stuff explain the logics of this to me, please?

Comment: In this case `A[0]` is a pointer because you have an array of pointers.

Comment: `&A[0]` is exactly the same thing as `A` in most contexts. Consequently, `&A[0][0]` is the same as `A[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fwrite()` wants a pointer to (the address of) the data to be written.

In this code:

```
int A[size];
```

`A` is an array of `int` values:

```
     [0] [1] [2] [...]
    +---+---+---+-----+
A = | x | x | x | ... |
    +---+---+---+-----+
```

Where `A[0]` is the 1st `int` in that array, and `&A[0]` is a pointer to that 1st `int`.

So, this code would work:

```
fwrite(&A[0], sizeof(int), size, dogfile);
```

As would this code:

```
fwrite(A, sizeof(int), size, dogfile);
```

Because referring to a fixed array by its name alone will yield (ie it *decays* into) a pointer to its 1st element in various contexts, such as in a function parameter, or a variable assignment.

```
       [0] [1] [2] [...]
      +---+---+---+-----+
  A = | x | x | x | ... |
      +---+---+---+-----+
        ^
        |
fwrite(buffer, ...)
```

Now, in your code:

```
int ** A;
A = new int* [randomSize];
A[0] = new int [randomSize];
```

This is creating an array of `int*` pointers, where each `int*` points at its own array of `int` values:

```
     [0] [1] [2] [...]
    +---+---+---+-----+
A = | x | x | x | ... |
    +---+---+---+-----+
      |   |   |           [0] [1] [2] [...]
      |   |   |          +---+---+---+-----+
      +---|---|--------> | x | x | x | ... |
          |   |          +---+---+---+-----+
          |   |
          |   |           [0] [1] [2] [...] 
          |   |          +---+---+---+-----+
          +---|--------> | x | x | x | ... |
              |          +---+---+---+-----+
              |
              |           [0] [1] [2] [...]
              |          +---+---+---+-----+
              +--------> | x | x | x | ... |
                         +---+---+---+-----+
```

Where:

- `A[0]` is the 1st `int*` in that array, and `&A[0]` is a pointer to that `int*`
- `A[0][0]` is the 1st `int` pointed at by the 1st `int*` in `A`, and `&A[0][0]` is a pointer to that `int`
- And so on...

So, if you try to write `&A[0]` using this code:

```
fwrite(&A[0], sizeof(int), randomSize, dogfile);
```

You will write garbage to the file, because `A` is an array of `int*` pointers, and you are writing the values of those pointers themselves, not the values of the `int`s that they point to.

```
     [0] [1] [2] [...]
    +---+---+---+-----+
A = | x | x | x | ... |
    +---+---+---+-----+
     ^ |                  [0] [1] [2] [...]
     | |                 +---+---+---+-----+
     | +---------------> | x | x | x | ... |
     |                   +---+---+---+-----+
     +---+
         |
fwrite(buffer, ...)
```

This code works, though:

```
fwrite(A[0], sizeof(int), randomSize, dogfile);
```

Because `A[0]` is a pointer to the 1st `int` in another array.

```
     [0] [1] [2] [...]
    +---+---+---+-----+
A = | x | x | x | ... |
    +---+---+---+-----+
       |                  [0] [1] [2] [...]
       |                 +---+---+---+-----+
       +---------------> | x | x | x | ... |
                         +---+---+---+-----+
                           ^
                           |
         +-----------------+
         |
fwrite(buffer, ...)
```

Using `&A[0][0]` will also work, because it is also a pointer to that same `int`.

---

In general, when accessing array elements, brace syntax is just syntax-sugar for pointer arithmetic. `Array[Index]` is the same as `*(Array+Index)` <sup>1</sup>, and so `&Array[Index]` is the same as `&*(Array+Index)` <sup>2</sup>, which simplifies to just `Array+Index`.

<sup>1</sup>: meaning, take the starting address of `Array`, increment it by `Index` number of elements (ie by `Index` multiplied by `sizeof(element type)` number of bytes), and then dereference it to access the element at that address.

<sup>2</sup>: meaning take the starting address of `Array`, increment it by `Index` number of elements , dereference it to access the element, and then take the address of that element.